# unable to access kubernetes Service from NodePort

Tags: vagrant, kubernetes

I have a multi-host vagrant cluster w/ 2 workers as described in the coreos-vagrant tutorial [1].

I can't access my deployed services externally.  Currently, I'm trying `NodePort`. The services are all basic, non-auth rest APIs. On the service named `curly`, its port `6001` [2] should be accessible on `32001` against my cluster [3].  My Deployment & Service configs are shown below.

Cluster & services are up:

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://172.17.4.101:443
...

$ kubectl get services
NAME           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes     10.3.0.1     <none>        443/TCP          1d
stooge-curly   10.3.0.254   <nodes>       6001:32001/TCP   15m
stooge-larry   10.3.0.72    <nodes>       6001:32002/TCP   15m
stooge-moe     10.3.0.219   <nodes>       6003:32003/TCP   15m
```

Attempting to `GET http://172.17.4.101:32001/` or `GET http://10.0.2.15:32001/` both just *hang*.  172.17.4.101 is my master. 10.0.2.15 is one of my vagrant worker IPs [4].

- [1] https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-vagrant.html
- [2] https://github.com/cdaringe/hackweek-kubes/blob/master/stooges-all.yaml#L10
- [3] https://github.com/cdaringe/hackweek-kubes/blob/master/stooges-all.yaml#L67
- [4] https://gist.github.com/cdaringe/3c0f3459a90afa113c87cec3a24e4b1d

Answer (score 1):

< NodeAddress>:< NodePort> worked, however, the `label`s in each `Deployment` were not unique.  there was a common `label` in each Deployment, (`run: stooges`), but each also needed something else in the label hash.  that is, each `Deployment` label set must be *unique*.

the NodeAddress I tried above was also incorrect. `kubectl describe pods` gave me the node addrs of where my services were running. therefore, `GET 172.17.4.202:32001` responded per expectation